# How do I get full visual control of a terminal with node?

Tags: node.js, user-interface, terminal

I want to make the classic game 'Snake' as a CLI game using node.

To do so, I want to escape the 'printing text to the screen' terminal, and have control complete control (within a limited range of what's visually possible) of the terminal.

Happy to (and actually, preferable) to have the terminal act as a matrix of monospaced characters.

The terminal should still receive keyboard events.

Basically, think something like how Jest works in watch mode, or npm when you do a `npm init`.

I imagine finding the answer to this is quite easy - but I don't know what the term to google is.

**Update** I understand that I would use `process.stdout` for this. A good answer could show a simple of example of:

- Clearing the screen
- Drawing some arbitrary say in the middle of the screen
- Responding to keyboard events.

**Update 2** - I have created a utility library that helps do this here: [node-cli-character-matrix](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cli-character-matrix).

Under the hood it uses [ink](https://github.com/vadimdemedes/ink) for visual display and [keypress](https://www.npmjs.com/package/keypress) for capturing keyboard input.

Comment: update: I browsed into how jest is doing it - is it that you use `process.stdout` as a WriteStream? If that's the case a good answer would be demonstrating a basic usage of the technique.

Comment: I updated my answer to include how to get raw keyboard input. It took me longer to write that because I had to write a simple test program in node to experiment with. I've never done in in javascript so I ported my logic from a Tcl script I wrote a long time ago that implemented a text editor (that I use to this day: https://github.com/slebetman/tcled)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Output

For unix terminals (Linux, MacOS, WSL on Windows) they simply use sequences of normal bytes sent to your stdout to control everything. These are called escape sequences.

The protocol for this is the VT family of protocols which evolved from Teletype protocol (those typewriter machines you see in movies). VT stands for Video Terminal (because regular terminals in those days were dot matrix printers or teletype typewriter machines) and were a range of products sold by DEC.

The most popular model sold was the VT100. And so the most popular protocol emulated by software terminals these days are based on the VT100 protocol.

If you google "VT100 escape code" you will find documentation on how to control the terminal.

Once software started emulating these hardware terminals people wanted to standardize what features are supported (there were various terminals produced eg: VT52, VT100, VT102 etc.) so ANSI produced a standard, the X3.64, for text terminals (later also standardized by ECMA as ECMA-48). So optionally you can also google "ANSI escape code" to get what you want.

Wikipedia actually has quite a nice page on it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code. However I personally prefer to use something simpler like the following and avoid all the historical stuff on Wikipedia: https://espterm.github.io/docs/VT100%20escape%20codes.html

(note: some documentation denotes the ESC character as `^[` even though it is only a single byte: `0x1B`)

Note that Linux have further extended the ANSI control codes to include more features such as mouse support and RGB colors: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html

The way the escape codes work is simple. Print a non-printable character to tell the terminal what to do. For example to clear the screen you send:

```
ESC [ 2 J
```

Or in plain javascript:

```
console.log("\x1b[2J");
```

Of course `console.log()` will also send a newline (`"\n"` or `0x0A`) after printing your string but the line above should work. Obviously to avoid the newline on node you can use:

```
process.stdout.write("\x1b[2J"); // clear screen
```

Printing something somewhere random in the terminal, for example printing a smiley face at row=5 column=20, is just:

```
ESC [ 5 ; 2 0 H
```

Assuming of course your terminal supports utf8 (for the smiley face, it works without utf8 support if you just print regular ASCII characters). Or in node:

```
process.stdout.write("\x1b[5;20H");
```

You can easily make this reusable:

```
function goto (x, y) {
    process.stdout.write(`\x1b[${y};${x}H`);
}

function print (txt) {
    process.stdout.write(txt);
}

goto(20,5);
print('');
```

Of course, there are lots of libraries that help you control the terminal. Some of which also work on Windows console (my examples above generally don't work on Windows console but I've heard you can enable ANSI support in the terminal on Windows 10, I don't use Windows). Some of the more popular ones are:

- [chalk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chalk) which simply colors your text (but with a very nice API),
- [blessed](https://www.npmjs.com/package/blessed) which is a full-featured console UI framework,
- [terminal-kit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/terminal-kit) which is another full featured console framework
- and I must mention [ink](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ink) which allows you to use React.js on the console (it's not actually React, only React compatible API) which was mind-blowing to me.

## Input

Getting raw input from the terminal is not so straightforward. Usually your `stdin` will be line-buffered by the terminal by default. This means you will not see any keyboard events until the Enter key is pressed. You need to turn off line buffering if you want raw key presses from the keyboard. Unfortunately node does not have anything built-in to help you do this. Fortunately unix does have standard tools to enable raw input.

The following commands enable and disable raw modes and is known to work on both Linux and BSD (eg. MacOS):

```
# turn on raw mode, turn off echo
stty raw -echo

# turn off raw mode, turn on echo
stty -raw echo
```

The following is a simple program in node.js that accept raw keyboard inputs (useful if you want to know what the codes for ctrl-x or arrow keys or the F3 key are):

```
#! /usr/bin/env node

const exec = require('child_process').execSync;

exec('stty raw -echo', {
    stdio: 'inherit' // this is important!
});

process.stdin.on('data', input => {

    console.log(`${input.toString('hex')}\r`);
    // note: We add \r because in raw mode the terminal won't
    //       do it automatically for us.

    // Example of how to handle key presses:
    // Since we are in raw mode the terminal won't send the
    // kill signal to our process when we press ctrl-c so
    // we need to handle ctrl-c manually:
    if (input == '\x03') { // ctrl-c
        process.exit();
    }
});

process.on('exit', () => {
    // remember to restore normal terminal behavior:
    exec('stty -raw echo',{
        stdio: 'inherit' // this is important!
    });
});
```

You can add all your UI controller logic inside the `stdin.on('data')` callback.

Of course, for Windows you will need another answer (or question).

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. It looks like there is actually an undocumented 'keypress' event that the stdin will emit if it is TTY. There's a node module that provides a handy abstraction for this: https://github.com/TooTallNate/keypress

Comment: Very good answer, but there is one thing I would like to highlight: it seems the cursor positioning command coordinates start from 1, while I (wrongly) assumed they start from 0, like almost everything else in programming. Unfortunately, this caused me to waste a couple of hours debugging my code, but I hope my comment can save others from this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `process.stdout`(draw) and `process.stdin` (key press events) for this.
For animation (like a snake crawling), you need to remember the previous state, clear the terminal, and write a new, changed, state.
I saw a good example in [axel lib](https://github.com/F1LT3R/axel), it contains a link to example - [game blitzr](https://github.com/F1LT3R/blitzr)

Comment: Hi, a good example would demonstrate simple usage of how to clear the screen, draw in an arbitrary spot.

Comment: Ok, got it. Sorry if it was unuseful